# relativelayout space between its elements when background image is present

Tags: android, android-layout, layout

I have a relative layout with background image (9patch). I have set this image as background to the layout using xml. When I add another relative layout which has buttons and textviews, there is little space left before the new layout. I didnt set any padding. I also tried by setting padding top to 0. If i remove the background image the alignment will be proper with no space left on top of new layout. I have also tried by setting match parent and fill parent in new layout but still the space remains on top of it. The space left is very little like 3dp-5dp.

can someone suggest about this issue pls.

EDIT : space is on top of the new layout horizontally and i have tried setting gravity to top and also top left.

Comment: Can you please post your xml file code here..!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The black pixels on the top and left define the stretch area of the 9-patch, while the pixels on the bottom and right define the fill area. My guess is that you have a fill area defined that does not cover the entire right and bottom edges.

[Here's a good guide.](http://radleymarx.com/blog/simple-guide-to-9-patch/)